# Is there away to get folder names inside another folder?

Tags: php

I am searching for a way to get folder names inside my folder

to be clear this is what I want to do:

I have a folder that is located in my Desktop named 'myfiles'
under that folder I have tree folders 'Home','School' and 'Student'

Is that possible to get the  names of the tree folders inside 'myfiles' and echo them using PHP?

[image]

```
'myfiles' pure files = **C:\Users\sullanob\Desktop\myfiles**
```

in this way I can monitor and organized my folders using a web based application

thanks in advance..

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: then why somebody down voted my question :(

Comment: because you can google this probably.

Comment: because you haven't demonstrated effort, other than a question.  As it is your question is too broad.  If you have questions about a specific piece of code, this is the site.  If not, then this is not.  (and no, i was not the person who voted it down)

Comment: I see so I must have my code right? and will search first before asking here thanks bro.. more rooms for me for improvements :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PHP's [scandir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) function.

```
function listSubFolders($path) {
    return array_diff(scandir($path), array('.','..'));
}

var_dump(listSubFolders('C:/Users/sullanob/Desktop/myfiles'));
```

Comment: Thanks :)  but How to remove unnecessary text? I want to see only 'Home','Student' and 'School'?

Comment: You are going from asking a question to asking us to write the code for you, that is by the way most likely the reason some one down-vote your question. Search a bit in google, I'm sure you will find code examples, and if you have a specific question you are more than welcome.

Comment: I see thanks bro more rooms for me for improvement will get back here for any specific questions ..